# Accessing rows/columns/diagonals of a 2d matrix C#

Tags: c#, .net, matrix

I'd like to access the rows, cols and the diagonals of a 2d matrix. How can I do this correctly?

I'm planning to use this in a function where I will access a particular row, column or diagonal and then exit the nested loop.

I've tried the following example :

Considering a 2d matrix of chars :

```
char[,] board = { { 'O', 'O', 'O' }, { 'X', 'X', 'X' }, { 'O', 'O', 'O' } };

for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
    {

        // for example the second row where all the values are X
        if (board[i+1, j] == 'X' && board[i+1, j+1] == 'X' && board[i+1, j+2] == 'X')
        {
            Console.WriteLine(board[i+1, j]);
            Console.WriteLine(board[i+1, j+1]);
            Console.WriteLine(board[i+1, j+2]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are iterating through each "cell" in that inner loop.  If you want each rows then it's just one loop and the indexes [i,0] [i,1] [i,2]  The diagonals are just [0,0][1,1][2,2] and [2,0][1,1][0,2].

Comment: What are the purposes of the breaks? You are exiting each of your for loops immediately after their first iteration

Comment: @Rob Yeah that's a mistake sorry

Comment: @Daniel Calota, within your for loop you are also attempting to do the work that the for loop is doing. If you want to get all of the X's, just do Console.Write(board[1,0]); Console.Write(board[1,1]); Console.WriteLine(board[1,2]; otherwise you will increment i and j past the valid index values

Comment: @Rob What if you just check if it contains X?

Comment: 2 nested loops make no sense when all you want to check just one  row/column/diagonal... Can you please [edit] posts to clarify why you want nested loop?

Comment: @Daniel Calota if you want to check if the corresponding location contains an x, you would do a comparison operation: if(board[i,j]=='x') { Console.WriteLine($"X found at {i},{j}"); }

Comment: To be clear guys, I need this for a tic tac toe game. So... I would need to check strictly if an entire row/column/diagonal contains X / O, just consider X for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To read from the array in the method you want, omit the for loops and just access the array directly...

```
// Only X's
Console.Write(board[1, 0]);
Console.Write(board[1, 1]);
Console.WriteLine(board[1, 2]);
// Diagonal
Console.Write(board[0, 0]);
Console.Write(board[1, 1]);
Console.WriteLine(board[2, 2]);
```

Use the for loops if you want to iterate through and display all of the values contained within the array. Remove the i+1 or 2 and j+1 or 2 as these will end up exceeding the array's constraints and cause an error

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < board.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(board[i, j]);
    }
}
```

To search for winners, you can do something as simple as checking all 8 combinations:

```
if ((board[0, 0] == charToCompare && board[0, 1] == charToCompare && board[0, 2] == charToCompare) || //Row 1
(board[1, 0] == charToCompare && board[1, 1] == charToCompare && board[1, 2] == charToCompare) || //Row 2
(board[2, 0] == charToCompare && board[2, 1] == charToCompare && board[2, 2] == charToCompare) || //Row 3
(board[0, 0] == charToCompare && board[1, 0] == charToCompare && board[2, 0] == charToCompare) || //Col 1
(board[1, 0] == charToCompare && board[1, 1] == charToCompare && board[1, 2] == charToCompare) || //Col 2
(board[2, 0] == charToCompare && board[2, 1] == charToCompare && board[2, 2] == charToCompare) || //Col 3
(board[0, 0] == charToCompare && board[1, 1] == charToCompare && board[2, 2] == charToCompare) || //Diagonal Top to Bottom
(board[2, 0] == charToCompare && board[1, 1] == charToCompare && board[0, 2] == charToCompare)) //Diagonal Bottom to Top
{
    Console.WriteLine("Winner");
}
```

Or to modify your original code with 1 for loop and the breaks, you can do like so. There are probably much better ways, but effectively you will need to implement a routine to check for the solutions you desire

```
char[,] board = {   { 'X', 'O', 'O' }
                ,   { 'X', 'X', 'O' }
                ,   { 'O', 'X', 'X' } };

char charToCompare = 'X';

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
     if (board[i, 0] == charToCompare && board[i, 1] == charToCompare && board[i, 2] == charToCompare)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Winner Row {i}");
         break;
     }
     if (board[0, i] == charToCompare && board[1, i] == charToCompare && board[2, i] == charToCompare)
     {
         Console.WriteLine($"Winner Column {i}");
         break;
     }
}

if (board[0, 0] == charToCompare && board[1, 1] == charToCompare && board[2, 2] == charToCompare)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Winner diagonal top to bottom");
}

if (board[2, 0] == charToCompare && board[1, 1] == charToCompare && board[0, 2] == charToCompare)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Winner diagonal bottom to top");
}
```

Comment: That's helpful Rob. Thanks for the effort!